# How to turn serialization related variables to neat one-liners?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class that contains multiple public variables. And I would need different serialization/deserialization methods for subset of those variables (e.g. serialize variables **A** and **B** to **BSON**, then later on serialize variables **B**, **C**, **D**, **E** and **F** to **XML**).

All serialization/deserialization methods that are used and what variables should be handled via those methods are known compile time. So I should be able to turn these to neat one-liners that should tell coders what variables will be serialized/deserialized as groups.

I know that [Func and Action](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2010/11/passing-getter-and-setter-of-c-property.html) with get/set for Property + lambda expressions would make this more like

```
()=>SomeProperty, value => SomeProperty = value
```

but that isn't very neat since both **SomeProperty** and **value** are writed twice in one-liner (and I don't need **{get;set;}**).

Problem is that I don't know how to do that in C# (.NET framework 2.0). I would want to specify string and variable pairs that I could pass to both serialization and deserialization methods.

e.g. with following class

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int someNumber;
    public bool someBool;
    public string someString;
    public long someLong;
}
```

and in first case I would like to serialize **someBool** and **someLong**, so I would want to pass something like

```
var serializeThese = Dictionary<string, Variable>()
{
    { "boolish", this.someBool }, // this.someBool should be reference/pointer
    { "idNumber", this.someLong }, // this.someLong should be reference/pointer
};
```

to serialize method like

```
public string SerializeTheseVariables(Dictionary<string, Variable> dict)
{
    string output = "";
    foreach(var pair in dict)
    {
        output += pair.Key + ":" + pair.Value + "-";
    }
    return output;
}
```

or if I wanted to deserialize, then I would pass serializeThese to method like

```
public void ReinitFromBSON(BSON bson, Dictionary<string, Variable> dict)
{
    foreach(var pair in dict)
    {
        pair.Value = bson[pair.Key];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to use more than one serializaton, then it's a good time to start using [DTO](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8824/C-Data-Transfer-Object). Don't do anything with your original class, but provide methods to get/set bsonDTO and xmlDTO. Those are then used to serialize/deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

Split the instance to be (de)serialized from the definition of how (de)serialization should work.

Something like this:

```
var serializeThese = Dictionary<string, Variable>()
{
    { "boolish", nameof(this.someBool) },
    { "idNumber", nameof(this.someLong) },
};
```

(However, note that `nameof` is a feature of C# 6. Alternatively, passing in an `Expression` and digging the name of the field/property manually is an option.)

Then your (de)serialization routines would use this definition + an actual instance, and access fields / properties via reflection.

```
public string SerializeTheseVariables(Dictionary<string, Variable> serializationMetadata, object serializedInstance)
{
    …
}
```